# h:commandLink navigate to a section of the page

Tags: html, jsf, xhtml

I am using JSF and I want to navigate to a section of my page after clicking a button. My button is a `<h:commandLink>` and I am rendering the main form.

Comment: what have you tried so far? Not even a Google search?

Comment: I have search that, and I have found how to do this with an "a href" and using the id of the element where you want to navigate. I would appreciate a good answer. Thanks

Comment: What is a 'good' answer? Do you **need** an `h:commandLink` (do you actually know what a commandLink is for)? Then state so and state why. Otherwise if you do not need one, you have your good answer

Answer (score 0):

so if your page is question.xhtml you can use this

```
<a href="question.xhtml#myspan">Jump to span</a>
```

and jump to

```
<span id="myspan">myspan</span>
```

if you need it in jsf use the

```
<h:link value="Jump to myspan" fragment="myspan" />
```

It should generate the html code from above.

Comment: mkyong explains why and when a link or commandlink should be used in https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-link-commandlink-and-outputlink-example/

Comment: This is already answered in the duplicate.

Comment: And answers can be edited to add relevant info